# Hexo installation error in the windows environment

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, hexo

I tried to install Hexo in windows environment,but I always got same error messages, there are error messages.

```html
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\hexo -> C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hexo-cli\bin\hexo

> dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node scripts/install.js


> hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\hexo-util
> npm run build:highlight


> hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\hexo-util
> npm run build:highlight

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "F:\\softwareTwo\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "hexo-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! file C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;
npm ERR! path C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;

npm ERR! hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall: `npm run build:highlight`
npm ERR! spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall script 'npm run build:highlight'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hexo-util package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:highlight
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hexo-util
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hexo-util
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "F:\\softwareTwo\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "hexo-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall: `npm run build:highlight`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall script 'npm run build:highlight'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hexo-util package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:highlight
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hexo-util
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hexo-util
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "F:\\softwareTwo\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "hexo-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! file C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;
npm ERR! path C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd;

npm ERR! hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall: `npm run build:highlight`
npm ERR! spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall script 'npm run build:highlight'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hexo-util package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:highlight
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hexo-util
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hexo-util
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- (empty)

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe;D:\github\Git\cmd; ENOENT
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 (node_modules\hexo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: dtrace-provider@0.8.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status -4058
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "F:\\softwareTwo\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "hexo-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.9.5
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall: `npm run build:highlight`
npm ERR! Exit status -4058
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hexo-util@0.6.0 postinstall script 'npm run build:highlight'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the hexo-util package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build:highlight
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs hexo-util
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls hexo-util
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\xampp\htdocs\Git\npm-debug.log
```

I have updated node and npm to the latest version, cleared the npm cache, but they are still useless. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: have you installed git  https://git-scm.com ?

Comment: yes, I have installed git, and I execute [npm install -g hexo-cli] in git bash.

Comment: do you have a new ish version of npm? you can install the latest with npm install -g npm

Comment: Thanks,  I have updated npm.